# Sql:Iterate over varchar values using for loop

Tags: sql, for-loop

I want to iterate over some varchar values using for loop in sql but it seems it is not possible. Wherever i look for examples it seems for loop can only iterate over integer values and not varchar values in sql.
Is it true?
Following is my sql code

```
declare
@exist number
my_array=('100161','100164','102226','100143','108942','106922','108949','107191','100098','107182','107193','98646','100102','100105','103044','103293','103296','103297','104178','103018','104145','103017','103019','108991','108995','109000','103020','102121','103021','106284','103951','100117','102872','102873','100125','101582','102234','103027','103028','102225','101574','106964','106969','108956','109719','101581','102346','106997','107028','107030','107031','107070','102347','107083','107084','107085','107086','103633','107124','100191','100172','100204','104148','104163','100190','107180','109849','109852','110047','107473','107502','100091','100096','106265','108346','108222','109382','107814','107823','108167','109359','100171','103300','108268','108300','108860','108982','102342','102344','100089','108675','108880','109341','109875','109877','109884','108854','101912','102829','103317','104323','104324','104389','107239','108271','108273','108275','108277','108279','108872','108885','108957','108983','109878','109148','109279','109399','109443','109922','103318','109448','109452')
for i in my_array
@exist=select id from BacktestingCriteria where nodeId=i and hierarchyViewId=16008 and varCriteriaId=16 and pnlCriteriaId=3;
if @exist is null
insert into BacktestingCriteria(nodeId,hierarchyViewId,varCriteriaId,pnlCriteriaId) values
(i,16008,16,3)
@exist=select id from BacktestingCriteria where nodeId=i and hierarchyViewId=16008 and varCriteriaId=16 and pnlCriteriaId=4;
if @exist is null
insert into BacktestingCriteria(nodeId,hierarchyViewId,varCriteriaId,pnlCriteriaId) values
(i,16008,16,4)
end loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using **number in VARCHAR column**, so you can **cast value in integer** where use looping:

```
@exist=select id from BacktestingCriteria where nodeId= CAST(i as INT) and hierarchyViewId=16008 and varCriteriaId=16 and pnlCriteriaId=3;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, there is no FOR LOOP. However, you simulate the FOR LOOP using the WHILE LOOP.Generally work is done before the integer is incremented. A lot of for loops in SQL actually use that integer in their work (iterating from row to row or result to result in temp tables) and may be thrown off if the increment happens at the beginning of the cycle rather than the end.

There is no for-loop, only the while-loop:

```
DECLARE @x int = 0

WHILE @x < 10
BEGIN
    SET @x = @x + 1
    /* work to be done */
END
```